# SyntaxError: invalid syntax noseOfYeti -> on it statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose

I have started using the noseOfYeti plugin for nosetests. So far it works pretty well; the only thing it keeps having issues with is when I add a "before_each:" part to the tests. Here is my code:

```
# coding: spec    

from .context import get_elbs

from nose.tools import set_trace; 
from unittest import TestCase

describe TestCase, "Initialize":

    it "creates a GetELBs object":
        mock_aws_connection = ''
        elb_finder = get_elbs.GetElbs(mock_aws_connection)
        self.assertIsInstance(elb_finder, get_elbs.GetElbs)

    describe "get_account_elbs":
        before_each:
            pass

        it "returns a list of elbs":
            pass
```

and the command I run:

```
nosetests --with-noy
```

output:

```
D:\dev\git_repos\platform-health>nosetests --with-noy
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (test_get_elbs.py, line 19))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\apps\python\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "d:\apps\python\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "d:\apps\python\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "D:\dev\git_repos\platform-health\tests\unit_tests\test_orphan_elb_finder\test_get_elbs.py", line 19
    it "returns a list of elbs":
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I am following the documentation here:

https://noseofyeti.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

My syntax looks the same, so I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

Comment: As the example explains, Nose of yeti is its own language and translates to Python only after you've registered its plugin with nose and include the "# coding: spec" line at the top of the file. Have you also taken those steps?

Comment: Hey Mate, yeah sorry I forgot to add those pieces into the main question. I have updated it.

Comment: Not sure if that is the case but have you tried inserting an empty line right after before_each? https://github.com/delfick/nose-of-yeti/issues/3 or https://noseofyeti.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#before-each-and-after-each

Comment: Thats for the reply mate. I tried your suggestion adn I'm still getting the same error :(